# Excel formula to search a cell value in a row and fill it with an equivalent value?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office

I have this example excel file:

[image]

I want to write a formula in B (column) to search names in A (column) in second table and if it exists, fill it with it's ID value. Is it possible? Final result should be like this:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `XLOOKUP()` function or using `VLOOKUP()` function

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>B2</kbd>

```
=XLOOKUP(A2:A7,D2:D4,E2:E4,"")
```

---

With `VLOOKUP()` you need an error control that is one would need to wrap the formula within an `IFERROR()` or `IFNA()`, while `XLOOKUP() function's` 4th` parameter fulfills that.

```
=IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2:A7,D2:E4,2,0),"")
```

---

Comment: Thanks. By the way, XLOOKUP doesn't work on office 2016 but VLOOKUP is OK.

Comment: @MohammadH glad you are able to resolve, btw I wasn't aware of your excel version, therefore posted both ways.